# How to retrieve contents from an asp page using Forge API?

Tags: trigger.io

I am new to Trigger.IO and was wondering if someone can provide a complete example to get content from an external asp page. Basically, i am trying to achieve similar to the following code but with Forge API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showHint(str)
            {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str.length==0)
              { 
              document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
              return;
              }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.asp?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
        <form action=""> 
            First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
        </form>
        <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks
B Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but you're probably looking for the `forge.request.ajax` method:

```
function showHint(str) {
  if (!str) { return; }

  if (str.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }

  forge.request.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://my.server.com/gethint.asp',
    data: { q: str },
    success: function(response) {
      if (!response) { return; }
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=response;
    }
  });
}
```

Check out the [Trigger.io forge.request documentation](https://trigger.io/modules/request/current/docs/index.html) for more advanced options.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. Only a minor change was required. document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=response; It works perfect on Andriod. Can't wait to test it on ios.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! Changed my answer to only use ´response´.